# WP Query - Unable to query by category slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, args

I have four categories in my Custom Post Type of "projects" that are 'live', 'heal', 'work', and 'play'.  I have a few 'projects' posts with no category that I would like to omit from the archive page.  In my archive, my query is as follows:

```
     <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'projects','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $projects_number, 'paged'=> $paged, 'category_name' => 'work,play,live,heal'); ?>
        <?php $wp_query = null; ?>
        <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

But my archive is not returning any projects. I also tried the 'cat' parameter with id's but no avail there either.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this...the 'category' argument needed to be in its own array